# About SP2013 farm configuration wizard

Tags: configuration-wizard

Once we have installed SP2013 binary and completed product configuration wizard, login to Central Admin page, it will ask you to launch the Farm Configuration Wizard.

Everytime I ran it, after select the services I need, it will jump to a page saying "Working on it... This shouldn't take long". But every time it keep me waiting. My questions are:

1. According to my understanding, the wizard is trying to setup different service application. The timer job will keep running the setup even though I close the browser. So it is safe to just close the browser and work on other configuration in Central Admin?
2. Anyway to monitor the progress of wizard?
3. After I completed the Product configuration wizard and start the Central Admin first time, should I login with the install account or the farm admin? Will it make any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First As per my experience i would highly recommend don't to use the farm configuration wizard for provisioning all services apps. I always run it 1st time for state service.

1. Yes you can close it, it will not effect the anything.
2. You can check the progress from **Check Running job status** section of **Monitoring**
3. it really doesn't matter under which account you login. But it depend what you are doing, i.e if you are provisioning the UPS services you need to login with farm admin account

Comment: Thanks for your answers for 3 questions. However what do you mean by "run it 1st time for state service" but "don't use the wizard"?

Comment: @Mark For the state service application is there is no built-in UI for it. So you would have to select it with the wizard or use powershell to create it. Personally I would use powershell for it since SharePoint likes to end all of it's database names with GUIDs. This link here will tell you how to create a state service application using powershell. [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608084(v=office.15).aspx) use example 2.

Comment: As Zingwing Explain it. Only reason I never use is creating ugly content Dtabase name...1st time means, when you create a new farm at that time when you run config wizard on 1st server then create the state services after that all the time cancel it.